# Using Authentication Service with Silverlight Business Application

Tags: security, silverlight-5.0

I learned that the Silverlight Business Application template allows you to create users.

But you can also create users with the Web Site Administration Tool.

What I see is that the Administration tool allows you to create roles, and allows assigning users to those roles, whereas the pre built interface that the template offers only allows to create users which assigns them to the "Registered Users" role automatically.

I guess that if I want to offer the ability of creating roles and managing the relationship "roles-users" from the application, I should program the interface in the application. **is that so?**

I see that the pre-built interface the business template offers is very limited.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in interface of the SL business application aims to allow a new user to create an acount and log on/off. It doesn't concern itself with actual user rights. You have to implement this separately.

I usually implement this by adding a "Settings" view in the SL app where I put a datagrid and populate (from the aspnetdb.mdf) the registered users as rows and the role names as columns.
Then for each row I put a checkbox to allow a "PowerUser" to assign each new user to roles.

To do this you have to first create (through SL or Web Site Administration Tool) at least one user ("PowerUser") and 2 roles: "NormalUserRole", "PowerUserRole".
Then you assign PowerUser to the PowerUserRole and grant him access to the Settings Page.

So:

- Anone (no assigned role)-> can create a new user account and log on/off. No other rights
- UserRole -> can work on site
- PowerUserRole ->   can assign roles to users